# NS records in Route53 not updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I recently purchased a new domain (stagesz.com) in AWS route53 and deleted the original hosted zone then created a new one and now when I check the ns records at a service like https://www.websitepulse.com/tools/ns-records-lookup-test# it shows a different group of records than what's listed in the route53 hosted zone.

```
DNS Lookup: 
ns-660.awsdns-18.net
ns-357.awsdns-44.com
ns-1953.awsdns-52.co.uk
ns-1489.awsdns-58.org
```

The AWS allocated records listed in the Route 53 hosted zone are

```
Route53 Name servers:
ns-18.awsdns-02.com
ns-622.awsdns-13.net
ns-1172.awsdns-18.org
ns-1765.awsdns-28.co.uk
```

I've waited 5 days since the last update to see if they would eventually update but it has not.

This problem is preventing us from verifying our ssl and pointing the domain to our application server.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently the output of `whois stagesz.com` is clearly showing the old NS records. This is because creating a Route 53 hosted zone doesn't automatically change the domain registration settings.

Based on your whois data and your question, you are using Amazon itself as your registrar. In that case, you need to change the NS records in Registered Domains sections in Route 53 (not just your hosted zone). The following documentation gives steps on how to change the name servers via console. Make sure you change the records correctly since NS records usually have a high TTL:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing